# android studio creating an app and it generates with errors

Tags: android-studio

When i create an new project it just creates it with errors without some keywords, close sentences,etc

I have no clue for what reason it happens

```
   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:994)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:176)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:184)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:139)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:92)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:101)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ValueResourceParser2.parseDocument(ValueResourceParser2.java:212)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ValueResourceParser2.parseFile(ValueResourceParser2.java:91)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceSet.createResourceFile(ResourceSet.java:553)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceSet.parseFolder(ResourceSet.java:485)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceSet.readSourceFolder(ResourceSet.java:291)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.DataSet.loadFromFiles(DataSet.java:252)
```

It points to that file [image: error]

It happens every time i try to create a new project.
I expect it to create without errors.

Comment: exactly What is the issue..?

Comment: Like i told it just creates a new project with missing parts and when i try to run it, it just points m to the errors

Comment: Have you tried importing an android project (from git or some other source)? If yes, what is the result?

Comment: Yes works as it should be